# ThreadPool with boost::asio does not quit?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, threadpool

I have the following minmal example of a thread pool made with boost::asio.

```
#include <queue>
#include <map>

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp> // remove me (only for io)

class ThreadPool
{
public:
    void work_as_mainthread(void) { m_io_service.run(); }

    ThreadPool(int poolSize = 4) : timer(m_io_service)
    {
        timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1)); // this line does not affect the problem
        m_pWork.reset( new boost::asio::io_service::work(m_io_service) );

        for ( int i = 0; i < poolSize; ++i)
            m_threadGroup.create_thread( boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &m_io_service) );
    }

    ~ThreadPool()
    {
        m_pWork.reset();
        m_threadGroup.join_all();
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service m_io_service;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> m_pWork;
    boost::thread_group m_threadGroup;
};

int main()
{
    int n_threads = 2;
    ThreadPool pool(n_threads);
    pool.work_as_mainthread();
    // this line is never reached...
    return 0;
}
```

If you like, you can compile it like this:

```
g++ -Wall -g -lboost_thread -lboost_date_time -lboost_system main.cpp -o main
```

What makes me wonder is that the program does not stop. What I do is calling io_service::run, but without any "work" for it. io_services without work quit themselves, as said in the boost::asio docs. Now, why does my program never quit?

Comment: For thread pooling implementations, it may be worthwhile to read the [effects of exceptions thrown from handlers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.effect_of_exceptions_thrown_from_handlers) and consider [avoiding the heap](http://think-async.com/Asio/TipsAndTricks?skin=clean.nat%2casio%2cpattern#Stopping_the_io_service_from_run) by using `boost::optional` instead of `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a `boost::asio::io_service::work` object, that keeps the `io_service` from completing.

```
// This line keeps the io_service running
m_pWork.reset( new boost::asio::io_service::work(m_io_service) );
```

If you want it to stop, you would need to destroy that work object, like this:

```
// stop the worker(s)
m_pWork.reset();
```

It's up to you to find an appropriate time/place to do this.  I would suggest calling `timer.async_wait()`, then in the handler you can reset your work object to see how this all should be working together.

See [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) portion of the documentation.

Comment: Also, because he is creating the `work`, then having the main thread itself call `io_service::run()`, nothing exits.  As written, when the Thread Pool goes out of scope, it destroys the work object, but it won't be destroyed because the main is doing the running.

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer. Only to be sure I got it: The work object is a "pseudo-task" besides all the "real" tasks. And its only use is to keep the thread pool alive?

Comment: Thanks. One last question: Is the ioservice::work class only made for these non existing tasks? Or is it also used for "real" tasks?

Comment: It's only a sentinel object to indicate to the `io_service` that there may be real work to do.  It's not used to actually perform any real work.