# Data is getting discarded in TCP/IP with boost::asio::read_some?

Tags: sockets, network-programming, boost-asio

I have implemented a TCP server using `boost::asio`. This server uses `basic_stream_socket::read_some` function to read data. I know that `read_some` does not guarantee that supplied buffer will be full before it returns.

In my project I am sending strings separated by a delimiter(if that matters). At client side I am using `WinSock::send()` function to send data. Now my problem is on server side I am not able to get all the strings which were sent from client side. My suspect is that `read_some` is receiving some data and discarding leftover data for some reason. Than again in next call its receiving another string.

Is it really possible in TCP/IP ?

I tried to use `async_receive` but that is eating up all my CPU, also since buffer has to be cleaned up by callback function its causing serious memory leak in my program. (I am using `IoService::poll()` to call handler. That handler is getting called at a very slow rate compared to calling rate of `async_read()`).

Again I tried to use free function `read` but that will not solve my purpose as it blocks for too much time with the buffer size I am supplying.

My previous implementation of the server was with `WinSock API` where I was able to receive all data using `WinSock::recv()`. 
Please give me some leads so that I can receive complete data using `boost::asio`.

here is my server side thread loop

```
void 
TCPObject::receive()
{
    if (!_asyncModeEnabled)
    {
        std::string recvString;
        if ( !_tcpSocket->receiveData( _maxBufferSize, recvString ) )
        {
            LOG_ERROR("Error Occurred while receiving data on socket.");
        }
        else
            _parseAndPopulateQueue ( recvString );
    }
    else
    {
        if ( !_tcpSocket->receiveDataAsync( _maxBufferSize ) )
        {
            LOG_ERROR("Error Occurred while receiving data on socket.");
        }
    }
}
```

receiveData() in TCPSocket

```
bool 
TCPSocket::receiveData( unsigned int bufferSize, std::string& dataString )
{
   boost::system::error_code error;
   char *buf = new char[bufferSize + 1];
   size_t len = _tcpSocket->read_some( boost::asio::buffer((void*)buf, bufferSize),        error);
   if(error)
   {
       LOG_ERROR("Error in receiving data.");
       LOG_ERROR( error.message() );
       _tcpSocket->close();
       delete [] buf; 
       return false;
   }
   buf[len] ='\0';
   dataString.insert( 0, buf );
   delete [] buf;
   return true;
}
```

receiveDataAsync in TCP Socket

```
bool 
TCPSocket::receiveDataAsync( unsigned int bufferSize )
{
    char *buf = new char[bufferSize + 1];

    try
    {
        _tcpSocket->async_read_some( boost::asio::buffer( (void*)buf, bufferSize ), 
                                     boost::bind(&TCPSocket::_handleAsyncReceive, 
                                                    this,
                                                    buf,
                                                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred) );
        //! Asks io_service to execute callback
        _ioService->poll();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        LOG_ERROR("Error Receiving Data Asynchronously");
        LOG_ERROR( e.what() );
        delete [] buf;
        return false;
    }

    //we dont delete buf here as it will be deleted by callback _handleAsyncReceive
    return true;
}
```

Asynch Receive handler

```
void 
TCPSocket::_handleAsyncReceive(char *buf, const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t size)
{
    if(ec)
    {
        LOG_ERROR ("Error occurred while sending data Asynchronously.");
        LOG_ERROR ( ec.message() );
    }
    else if ( size > 0 )
    {
        buf[size] = '\0';
        emit _asyncDataReceivedSignal( QString::fromLocal8Bit( buf ) );
    }
    delete [] buf;
}
```

Client Side sendData function.

```
sendData(std::string data)
{
    if(!_connected)
    {
        return;
    }

    const char *pBuffer = data.c_str();

    int bytes = data.length() + 1;

    int i = 0,j;
    while (i < bytes)
    {
        j = send(_connectSocket, pBuffer+i, bytes-i, 0);

        if(j == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            _connected = false;
            if(!_bNetworkErrNotified)
            {
                _bNetworkErrNotified=true;
                emit networkErrorSignal(j);
            }
            LOG_ERROR( "Unable to send Network Packet" );
            break;
        }
        i += j;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want help, then post your code.  Include the server code as well as the client code becasue the problem(s) could be in either or both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost.Asio's TCP capabilities are pretty well used, so I would be hesitant to suspect it is the source of the problem.  In most cases of data loss, the problem is the result of application code.

In this case, there is a problem in the receiver code.  The sender is delimiting strings with `\0`.  However, the receiver fails to proper handle the delimiter in cases where multiple strings are read in a single read operation, as `string::insert()` will cause truncation of the `char*` when it reaches the first delimiter.

For example, the sender writes two strings `"Test string\0"` and `"Another test string\0"`.  In `TCPSocket::receiveData()`, the receiver reads `"Test string\0Another test string\0"` into `buf`.  `dataString` is then populated with `dataString.insert(0, buf)`.  This particular overload will copy up to the delimiter, so `dataString` will contain `"Test string"`.  To resolve this, consider using the `string::insert()` overload that takes the number of characters to insert: `dataString.insert(0, buf, len)`.

Comment: Thank You for you reply.. !
I will definitely try this and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used the poll function before.  What I did is create a worker thread that is dedicated to processing ASIO handlers with the run function, which blocks.  The Boost documentation says that each thread that is to be made available to process async event handlers must first call the io_service:run or io_service:poll method.  I'm not sure what else you are doing with the thread that calls poll.

So, I would suggest dedicating at least one worker thread for the async ASIO event handlers and use run instead of poll.  If you want that worker thread to continue to process all async messages without returning and exiting, then add a work object to the io_service object.  See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095258/threadpool-with-boostasio-does-not-quit) for an example.

Comment: but run blocks caller thread permanently.. I am not doing any other processing in the thread that calls poll except for above mentioned `TCPObject::receive()` function. I am not sure why it is eating up that much resources and why handler calling rate is slower.